# Join query structure in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Assume this is a SQL query.

```
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wm1 ON (
                               wm1.post_id = p1.id
                               AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
                               AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
                               )
```

How can i execute this query in laravel structure ??

Answer (score 0):

are you sure, that

```
AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
```

is part of join statement? may be it's good idea to move this to where clause

Comment: yaa i can but i want to know how can i do it in left join.

Comment: Eshaan Dil Logical, you are trying to use left join clause for cases that processing with where clause. Of course you could try. May be in some sql server versions it would be okay, but try to move it to where clause of this query or you could write subquery LEFT JOIN (select <only fields you would use> wp_postmeta where meta_value IS NOT NULL) wm1 ON (
                               wm1.post_id = p1.id
                               AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
                               )  using of subquery can give you benefits in some cases